# Rails form_for added empty model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have started the "Get Started Guide" from the ruby on rails website. Everything works fine, but when I change the order of *showing all comments* and than *display the comments-form* in the other way round, than the `form_for`function adds a empty comments model to `@post.comments` and so, I display one empty comment in the loop.
Here is the view:

```
<h1><%= @post.name %></h1>
<p><%= @post.text %></p>
<h2>Add comment</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

The loop display two comments. One, that exists in the db and one, that has just empty attributes. If I delete the form, than all is shown up correct.

Comment: You should also display your posts controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only your persisted comments:

`<%= render @post.comments.select(&:persisted?) %>`

Answer (score 1):

When you do post.comments.build against some post, it will be added to the post.comments collection and will be displayed along with other comments.

You can always use persisted to check if the object is present in database meaning id is assigned to it.

```
 @post.comments.select(&:persisted?)
```

Note: .present? check donot work here so you have to use .persisted.?
present check only assosiated to the parent.